# How about indexing Hinduism SE with Google?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Whenever I search for queries relating to Hinduism, Hinduism SE won't appear in top search results in Google. However questions on Quora appear in top search results, though this site has good answers when compared to Quora. I need to type two more key words "hinduism stack" at end of my query. If answers of this site appear as top search results, it will be helpful to questioners and it also helps in expanding this site.

Do we need to index Hinduism SE with Google? Why doesn't this site appear in top search results?

Comment: Google does index this site.  And at least I frequently see my own questions at the top of Google search results.  If you just look through my questions and search two words from any one of my titles, most of the time my question will appear at or near the top.

Comment: I think the issue is that my questions tend to be on obscure subjects, whereas other people's questions are on subjects where there's a lot more competition from other websites, so they may appear lower in search results.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan How can we make this site appear on top?

Comment: It depends on google ranking and word match. I don't know much details either.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14056/260388

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly the site already *is* indexed (otherwise you wouldn't find it by adding those words to your query either). The only thing left is ranking better than other sites dealing with the same topics.

That will only come with time and more quality content. The more people that do come to the site actually find what they are looking for and the more content on related topics that is also useful to people the higher search rankings will climb. There is not some magic formula to follow. Just make good content that is actually useful and keep doing it.

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever I search for queries relating to Hinduism, Hinduism SE won't
>   appear in top search results in Google.

Well, this depends on the query terms of the searched query vs what is titled in Hinduism SE. Many questions on Hinduism SE have got refined, edited and it's very much accurate and detailed, but if it does not match with the query terms of user, Quora or any other site will come on the top.

> Do we need to index Hinduism SE with Google? Why doesn't this site
>   appear in top search results?

Since Google is bringing in lots of semantic web mining techniques like Knowledge graph and considering micro tags, with passing time there will be a surly improvement in search results.

What we can do?

1. Accurate Tags
2. Use of common query terms in description and Title (But not at cost of accuracy)
3. More Question

Hope this helps.